# NHibernate 3.0 - Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS."

Tags: nhibernate, linq-to-nhibernate

We are trying to upgrade to NHibernate 3.0 and now i am having problem with the following Linq query. It returns "Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS." error.

This is the linq query in the controller.

```
var list = (from item in ItemTasks.FindTabbedOrDefault(tab)
                    select new ItemSummary
                               {
                                   Id = item.Id,
                                   LastModifyDate = item.LastModifyDate,
                                   Tags = (from tag in item.Tags
                                           select new TagSummary
                                                      {
                                                          ItemsCount = tag.Items.Count,
                                                          Name = tag.Name
                                                      }).ToList(),
                                   Title = item.Title
                               });
```

and the following is the sql generated for this query

```
select   TOP ( 1 /* @p0 */ ) item0_.Id             as col_0_0_,
                 item0_.LastModifyDate as col_1_0_,
                 (select (select cast(count(* ) as INT)
                          from   dbo.ItemsToTags items3_,
                                 dbo.Item item4_
                          where  tag2_.Id = items3_.Tag_id
                                 and items3_.Item_id = item4_.Id),
                         tag2_.Name
                  from   dbo.ItemsToTags tags1_,
                         dbo.Tag tag2_
                  where  item0_.Id = tags1_.Item_id
                         and tags1_.Tag_id = tag2_.Id) as col_2_0_,
                 item0_.Title          as col_3_0_ from     dbo.Item item0_ order by item0_.ItemPostDate desc
```

ps:If i remove the Tags property in the linq query, it works fine.

Where is the problem in the query?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How did you write this query in an earlier version of NHibernate?

Comment: It was populating all properties of the repository like var list = ItemTasks.FindTabbedOrDefault(tab).where(x=>x.ItemPostDate = Datetime.today);

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same Generic ADO Exception error, I think it's actually the limitation of SQL server;
Is it possible somehow load object graph with projections in collections?

If I try this one:

```
var cats = q.Select(t => new cat()
                                          {
                                              NickName = t.NickName,
                                              Legs = t.Legs.Select(l => new Leg()
                                                                            {
                                                                                Color = l.Color,
                                                                                Size = l.Size
                                                                            }).ToList()
                                          }).ToList();
```

That does the same error..